# Making TabBarController Buttons link to first View Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

In the app I am working on I have the following navigation diagram:

SplashScreen (VC) - >TabBarController -> (item1) Navigation Controller -> Map   -> Homepage
                                      -> (item2) Navigation Controller -> List   ^

Preceding the TabBarController is a Splash Screen (UIViewController) with a single button that is attached to a modal seque leading to switchboard. All other segues are pushes.

Item #1 is a View Controller that contains a map of objects that contain links to a separate object homepage containing detailed information about the selected object.

Item #2 is a UITableViewController that has the list of objects and also links to the same object homepage UIViewController.

Both of these are also nested in Navigation Controllers that contain each item and the Buoy Homepage.

Right now if you select a Buoy on the map and bring up the buoy homepage for it, and then go to the list tab and select a buoy, if you go back to select the map tab again it still displays the homepage for the first selected buoy.

What I would like to do is have it so when the user clicks either tab it takes them directly to either the map, or the list - never back to a previously selected buoy.

I've been searching around for awhile and the closest that I've come is this, in my AppDelegate.m inside of didSelectViewController:

```
    NSInteger tag = viewController.tabBarItem.tag;

if (tag == 4)
{
    NSLog(@"Map Button........");

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheMap"]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController;
    [navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

This takes me back to the map, but without the navigation elements from either Nav Controller.

This is my first iOS app and I have gone through some of Apple's Docs and looked through their sample code but I haven't found one that specifically addresses my issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The viewController being passed to `tabBarController:didSelectViewController` should be your navigation controller.  So you should be able to invoke its popToRootViewController method.

Comment: Thanks for respoding! And sorry for my slow response.
<br/>
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{ 
    [viewController popToRootViewController];

----

This is what I am trying to do, but its telling me that there is no interface for popToRootViewController

Comment: Thanks for respoding! And sorry for my slow response. 
<br/>
`- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{ 
    [viewController popToRootViewController];`

----

This is what I am trying to do, but its telling me that there is no interface for popToRootViewController